# MySQL INSERT query not working in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've been stuck into a problem for several hours now. I'm building a stored procedure in MYSQL with lots of Inserts in new physical tables. The following is just a sample that I'm unable to get running in my MySQL server.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `someProc`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `someProc`()
BEGIN


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

SET @SQL1 = '   CREATE TABLE `table1` (`last_updated` INT); 

                INSERT INTO `table1` (`last_updated`)
                VALUES (1); ';
-- select @SQL1;


PREPARE stmt2 FROM @SQL1;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Upon invoking the stored proc, I get a MySQL error code 1064 saying that a error exists around `'INSERT INTO`table1`(`last_updated`)`.

But I can run the String contents assigned to the @SQL1 variable as a valid MySQL query and get the table created as well as the value inserted into it too. I've googled for the error code and  as suggested in the blogs/documentation pages, I don't think I'm using a reserved keyword here nor I'm inserting any incompatible datatypes. It's plain simple SQL that works outside of the stored procedure setting but fails miserably inside a proc. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: First thought is to remove the space before the `(`.  MySQL can be finicky about spaces before parentheses.

Comment: I just tried that but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare` prepares one statement.  This is clear in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html):

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

You need to split these two operations into two different statements.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help. I wish MySQL threw errors exactly specifying the problem rather than the generic codes. It would have been easier for the noobs like me.

Comment: @rstarter . . . I agree 1000%.  You noticed my original reaction:  "Oh it must be that weird thing with MySQL about spaces after functions (even though `insert` is not a function)."  Totally wrong, but then I remembered about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

use BI;
DROP PROCEDURE VCInplantFactProcedure;
DELIMITER //
Create Procedure VCInplantFactProcedure()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO fact_vcinplant_table (trip_id, dw_loader_id, dw_packer_id)
select ts.trip_id,dl.dw_loader_id,dp.dw_packer_id
from tbl_ap_trip_stagging ts left join dimension_loader dl on ts.loader_id=dl.loader
left join dimension_packer dp on ts.packer_id=dp.packer;

END//
DELIMITER ;

select insert working normally through stored procedure not working in my sql
kindly help